# SQL ORACLE Joining two queries together as one?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a set of tables like this[image: the results from DESC queries].

Also, here is a semi-accurate ERD to see what's going on.  [image: ERD]

I need to list all donations made by individual Alumni, and businesses. I need the first/last name and IDs present.

The following code returns all I need about the Alumni donors:

```
SELECT DonationID, Donation.AlumniID, BusinessID_FK, DONATIONDATE, Value, Alumnus.FirstName, Alumnus.LastName
FROM DONATION 
JOIN Alumnus 
   on Donation.AlumniID=Alumnus.alumniid;
```

And the following code returns all I need about the Business donors:

```
SELECT * FROM DONATION
JOIN BusinessSponser 
   on Donation.businessid_fk=businesssponser.businessid;
```

Furthermore, the following query returns all the IDs, however no First/Last names:

```
SELECT * FROM DONATION
LEFT JOIN BusinessSponser 
      on Donation.businessid_fk=businesssponser.businessid;
```

So my question is, how can I merge these queries together as one? My intention is to create a view that would display the final result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry but you don't get to decide whether your question should be deleted.  The StackOverflow Terms of Service mean your posts belong to the site , not you.  [Find out more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309255/146325).  If you genuinely want to thank the contributors who invested their time in trying to help you please learn the right way  to use this site.  Don't waste people's time again.

Answer (score 2):

The outer join is a SQL technique which allows us to join rows from one table with *some* rows from another table.  In your case you have two optional tables so you need *two* left outer joins:

```
select donationid
        , donation.donationdate
        , donation.value
        , donation.alumniid
        , alumnus.firstname
        , alumnus.lastname
        , donation.businessid
        , businesssponser.businessname
from donation 
left outer join alumnus 
    on donation.alumniid=alumnus.alumniid;
left outer join businesssponser 
    on donation.businessid_fk=businesssponser.businessid;
```